# Algorithm to combine two lists and evenly distribute the contents

Tags: algorithm, sorting

For example,

```
A { H, H, H, H, H, H, H, H }
B { T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T }
A+B { T, H, T, H, T, T, H, T, H, T, H, T, T, H, T, H, T, H }
```

I can't find a good solution to this, but I feel there must be a clean answer. 
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: assume `B.length >= A.length` (if not just swap references). Put `B.lenght/A.length` elements form B list, then one element from A list and repeat, do keep in mind in case of uneven division you need to sometimes put 1 more element

Comment: yes its that case of uneven division that's been throwing me off. In the case above, 10/8 = 1.25. How can I easily take this case into account and know when to add the doubles.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this in the future, here is the algorithm I made. It's not perfect but it seems to fit my needs just fine.

```
static List<T> CombineLists<T>( List<T> listA, List<T> listB )
{
    List<T> combinedList = new List<T>();
    List<T> longerList = (listA.Count > listB.Count) ? listA : listB;
    List<T> shorterList = (listA.Count > listB.Count) ? listB : listA;

    float listLengthRatio = (float)longerList.Count / (float)shorterList.Count;
    int longListCount = 0;
    int shortListCount = 0;

    while (longListCount < longerList.Count ||
        shortListCount < shorterList.Count)
    {
        while ( longListCount < shortListCount * listLengthRatio )
        {
            if ( longListCount < longerList.Count )
            {
                combinedList.Add( longerList[longListCount] );
                longListCount++;
            }
        }

        if ( shortListCount < shorterList.Count )
        {
            combinedList.Add( shorterList[shortListCount] );
            shortListCount++;
        }
    }

    return combinedList;
}
```